# Encoding returns "unknown"

Tags: z3, cvc4

For this example: http://pastebin.com/QyebfD1p z3 and cvc4 return "unknown" as result of check-sat. Both are not very verbose about the cause, is there a way to make z3 more verbose about its execution ?

Answer (score 2):

Your script uses the tactic

```
s = Then('simplify','smt').solver()
```

This tactic applies the Z3 simplifier, and then executes a "general purpose" SMT solver available in Z3. This solver is *not* complete for nonlinear arithmetic. It is based on a combination of: Simplex, Interval Arithmetic and Grobner Basis. One of the big limitations of this module is that it can't find models/solutions containing irrational numbers. In the future, we will replace this module with new nonlinear solvers available in Z3.

For nonlinear arithmetic, we usually suggest the nlsat solver available in Z3. This is a complete procedure and is usually very effective for unsatisfiable and satisfiable instances. You can find more about nlsat in [this article](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/files/IJCAR2012.pdf).
To use nlsat, we have to use

```
s = Tactic('qfnra-nlsat').solver()
```

Unfortunately, nlsat will get stuck in your example. It will get stuck computing [Subresultants](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subresultant.html) of very big polynomials produced during solving..

Z3 has yet another engine for handling nonlinear arithmetic. This engine reduces the problem to SAT. It is only effective on satisfiable problems that have solutions of the form `a + b sqrt(2)` where `a` and `b` are rational numbers. Using this engine, we can solve your problem in a very short amount of time. I attached the result in the end of the post. To use this engine, we have to use

```
s = Then('simplify', 'nla2bv', 'smt').solver()
```

**EDIT** Moreover, the tactic `nla2bv` encodes the rational numbers `a` and `b` as a pair of bit-vectors. By default, it uses bit-vectors of size 4. However, this value can be specified using the option `nlsat_bv_size`. This is not a global option, but an option provided to the tactic `nla2bv`. Thus, `nla2bv` can only find solutions of the form `a + b sqrt(2)` where `a` and `b` can be encoded using a small number of bits. If a satisfiable problem does not have a solution of this form, this tactic will fail and return `unknown`. 
**END EDIT**

Your example also suggests that we have to improve nlsat, and make it more effective as a model/solution finding procedure.
The current version gets stuck when trying to show that the problem has no solution. 
We are aware of these limitations and are working on new procedures to workaround them.

BTW, in the Python front-end, Z3 displays the models/solutions in decimal notation. However, everything is computed precisely. To get the precise representation of the solution. We can use the method `sexpr()`. For example, I changed your loop to

```
for d in m.decls():
    print "%s = %s = %s" % (d.name(), m[d], m[d].sexpr())
```

In the new loop, I'm displaying the result in decimal notation and the internal precise one. The meaning of `(root-obj (+ (* 2 (^ x 2)) (* 12 x) (- 7)) 2)` is the 2nd root of the polynomial `2*x^2 + 12x - 7`.

**EDIT**
Z3 provides [combinators](http://rise4fun.com/Z3py/tutorial/strategies) for creating non-trivial solvers. In the examples above, we used `Then` to perform the sequential composition of different tactics. We may also use `OrElse` to try different tactics. and `TryFor(t, ms)` that tries tactic `t` for `ms` milliseconds, and fails if the problem can't be solved in the given time.  These combinators can be used to create tactics that use different strategies for solving a problem. 
**END EDIT**

```
sat
Presenting results
traversing model...
s_2_p_p = 0.5355339059? = (root-obj (+ (* 2 (^ x 2)) (* 12 x) (- 7)) 2)
s_1_p_p = 0 = 0.0
s_init_p_p = 0.2928932188? = (root-obj (+ (* 2 (^ x 2)) (* (- 4) x) 1) 1)
s_2_p = 0.7071067811? = (root-obj (+ (* 2 (^ x 2)) (- 1)) 2)
s_1_p = 0 = 0.0
s_init_p = 0.2928932188? = (root-obj (+ (* 2 (^ x 2)) (* (- 4) x) 1) 1)
epsilon = 0 = 0.0
p_b2_s2_s_sink = 0.9142135623? = (root-obj (+ (* 4 (^ x 2)) (* 4 x) (- 7)) 2)
p_b2_s2_s_target = 0.0857864376? = (root-obj (+ (* 4 (^ x 2)) (* (- 12) x) 1) 1)
p_b2_s2_s_2 = 0 = 0.0
p_b2_s2_s_1 = 0 = 0.0
p_a2_s2_s_sink = 0 = 0.0
p_a2_s2_s_target = 0.8284271247? = (root-obj (+ (^ x 2) (* 4 x) (- 4)) 2)
p_a2_s2_s_2 = 0.1715728752? = (root-obj (+ (^ x 2) (* (- 6) x) 1) 1)
p_a2_s2_s_1 = 0 = 0.0
sigma_s2_b2 = 1 = 1.0
sigma_s2_a2 = 0 = 0.0
p_b1_s1_s_sink = 1 = 1.0
p_b1_s1_s_target = 0 = 0.0
p_b1_s1_s_2 = 0 = 0.0
p_b1_s1_s_1 = 0 = 0.0
p_a1_s1_s_sink = 1 = 1.0
p_a1_s1_s_target = 0 = 0.0
p_a1_s1_s_2 = 0 = 0.0
p_a1_s1_s_1 = 0 = 0.0
sigma_s1_b1 = 0 = 0.0
sigma_s1_a1 = 1 = 1.0
p_sinit_sink = 0.7071067811? = (root-obj (+ (* 2 (^ x 2)) (- 1)) 2)
p_sinit_target = 0.2928932188? = (root-obj (+ (* 2 (^ x 2)) (* (- 4) x) 1) 1)
p_sinit_2 = 0 = 0.0
p_sinit_1 = 0 = 0.0
s_sink = 0 = 0.0
s_target = 1 = 1.0
s_2 = 0.0857864376? = (root-obj (+ (* 4 (^ x 2)) (* (- 12) x) 1) 1)
s_1 = 0 = 0.0
s_init = 0.2928932188? = (root-obj (+ (* 2 (^ x 2)) (* (- 4) x) 1) 1)
```

**EDIT**
You can solve the problem in your comment by using the tactic

```
s = Then('simplify', 'nlsat').solver()
```

This tactic will solve the problem in a couple of seconds, and produce the solution in the end of the post. As I said above, `nlsat` is complete, but it may take very long time. 
Your problem is on the fringe of what the current version of Z3 can decide/solve automatically. We can combine different tactics with `OrElse` and `TryFor` to make it more stable. Example:

```
s = OrElse(TryFor(Then('simplify', 'nla2bv', 'smt', 'fail-if-undecided'), 1000),
           TryFor(Then('simplify', 'nlsat'), 1000),
           TryFor(Then('simplify', 'nla2bv', 'smt', 'fail-if-undecided'), 10000),
           Then('simplify', 'nlsat')).solver()
```

The tactic above tries the `nla2bv` approach for 1 sec, then `nlsat` for 1 sec, then `nla2bv` for 10 secs, and finally `nlsat` without a timeout.

I know this is not an ideal solution, but variations like that may be useful workarounds until the next solver for nonlinear arithmetic is ready. Moreover, Z3 has many other tactics that may be used to simplify/preprocess the problem before we invoke `nlsat`.
**END EDIT**

```
s_init = 15/32
s_1 = 7/16
s_2 = 1/2
s_target = 1
s_sink = 0
p_sinit_1 = 1/2
p_sinit_2 = 1/4
p_sinit_target = 1/8
p_sinit_sink = 1/8
sigma_s1_a1 = 1/2
sigma_s1_b1 = 1/2
p_a1_s1_s_1 = 1/2
p_a1_s1_s_2 = 1/4
p_a1_s1_s_target = 1/8
p_a1_s1_s_sink = 1/8
p_b1_s1_s_1 = 1/2
p_b1_s1_s_2 = 1/4
p_b1_s1_s_target = 1/16
p_b1_s1_s_sink = 3/16
sigma_s2_a2 = 1/2
sigma_s2_b2 = 1/2
p_a2_s2_s_1 = 1/2
p_a2_s2_s_2 = 1/4
p_a2_s2_s_target = 11/64
p_a2_s2_s_sink = 5/64
p_b2_s2_s_1 = 3/4
p_b2_s2_s_2 = 1/32
p_b2_s2_s_target = 9/64
p_b2_s2_s_sink = 5/64
epsilon = 1/4
s_init_p = 1649/3520
s_1_p = 797/1760
s_2_p = 103/220
s_init_p_p = 1809/3904
s_1_p_p = 813/1952
s_2_p_p = 127/244
```

**EDIT 2**
Your problems are on the fringe of what Z3 can do in a reasonable amount of time. Nonlinear real arithmetic is decidable, but is very expensive. Regarding debugging/tracing what is going on in Z3. Here are some possibilities:

- We can enable verbose messages using the command: `set_option("verbose", 10)`.
  The number is the verbosity level: 0 == "no message", and higher numbers == "more messages".
- Compile Z3 with support for tracing. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102789/printing-internal-solver-formulas-in-z3) for more information.
- Create a log of the Z3 APIs invoked by the Python program using the command `open_log("z3.log")`. This command should be invoked before any other Z3 API call. Then execute the log using the `z3` executable inside of `gdb`. 
  So, you will be able to stop the execution and find where Z3 is stuck. The `nlsat` solver usually gets stuck in two different places:

  1. Computing subresultants (the procedure `psc_chain` will be on the stack), and
  2. isolating the roots of polynomials with algebraic coefficients (the procedure `isolate_roots` will be on the stack).

Problem 2 will be soon fixed, after we replace the old algebraic number package with the [new one](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/blog/2013/02/02/inf-trans.html) that is much more efficient. Unfortunately, it seems your problems get stuck in the subresultant step.

Another remarks: although `nla2bv` was effective for your original benchmark, it is unlikely your new benchmarks will have a solution of the form `a + b sqrt(2)` where `a` and `b` are rational numbers. So, using `nla2bv` is just overhead. The tactic `nlsat` assumes the problem to be in CNF. So, for `pastebin.com/QRCUQE10`, we have to invoke `tseitin-cnf` before invoking `nlsat`. Another option is to use "big" tactic `qfnra-nlsat`. It invokes many pre-processing steps before invoking `nlsat`. However, some of these steps may make some problems harder to solve.

**END EDIT 2**

Comment: Dear Leonardo, Thank you for your answer. The solution got us going and I started to tweak the parameters. In other words I made all variables > 0 (only s_sink can be 0), after this change I am getting again "unknown" but now it takes ~20 minutes to get it. You can find the model here: http://pastebin.com/nh4KDMGW

Comment: The new problem can be solved using `s = Then('simplify', 'nlsat').solver()`. I updated the question. I also explained the behavior of `nla2bv` better. I marked the updates with **EDIT** ... **END EDIT**

Comment: Dear Leonardo, Another iteration on the same problem. Now I am getting unknown but after 20 minutes (I applied the rules that you were suggesting). Is there a way to get some debugging information from the z3 so I may be able to do debugging myself rather than asking so many questions ? Code of the model: http://pastebin.com/QRCUQE10

Comment: I updated the question with additional information. Please feel free to ask questions and report problems. We are currently working on new solvers for nonlinear arithmetic. It would be great if you could send us your problem set. They will definitely help us to improve Z3 and build better solvers.